# Is there a way to check if all children of an object are active?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am a beginner C# coder, and I am trying to make a game in Unity. Hence the question: Can I check if **all** children of an object are active in a scene? I want to use it to check if all enemies are active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check using:

```
for (int i = 0; i< gameObject.transform.childCount; i++)
{
    if(!gameoObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

[`activeInHierarchy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html) is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Extending [Johnny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204347/7111561)

Since [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) implements [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable) iteratign through all children you can easier loop using `foreach`

```
foreach(Transform child in transform) 
{ 
    if(child.gameObject.activeInHierachy) continue;

    return false;
}
return true;
```

Or using [`Linq Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Linq All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all)

```
using System.Linq;


bool allActive = transform.Cast<Transform>().All(child => child.activeInHierachy);
```

Comment: is using `foreach` for iterating through all children faster or more efficient than `for loop`?

Comment: @RichardJohnson afaik it should be about the same .. internally the [`GetEnumerator`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/73c12b5a403abad9a300f01a81e7aaf30a0d30b5/Runtime/Transform/ScriptBindings/Transform.bindings.cs#L326) also basically uses a self incrementing index and `GetChild` .. it is just way easier to write ;)